# Tkinter Top Level window Sizing

Tags: python, tkinter, resize, window, toplevel

I have been looking all over the web trying to find an a way to size a `TopLevel()` window in tkinter. I read the documentation and have been looking at [effbot.org's tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook). I see the options but I just can't seem to get them to work.

```
def test():
  top = Toplevel()
  top.title("test")

  msg = Message(top, text="test")
  msg.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


def test1():
  top = Toplevel()
  top.title("test1")

  msg = Message(top, text="test1")
  msg.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
```

I know that there are `height` and `width` options and there is also `root.geometry`. However I just cant seem to get anything with `TopLevel` to work...

Also, is the best way to create a new window through a definition and toplevel? All I am wanting is a pop-up window with some formatted text in it.

Comment: If all you want is a pop-up window with some text, why not just let `tkinter` automatically set the size? It'll adjust the window's size to fit its contents.

Comment: It just doesn't look right to me. I just want to resize it would top level be the best way of creating a new window if I wanted bigger windows?

Comment: If you hard-code the size it will break if you have different fonts or different resolution

Answer (score 7):

The following creates a root window then sets its size to 400x400, then creates a `Toplevel` widget and sets its size to 500x100:

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> root.geometry('400x400')
''
>>> top = tk.Toplevel()
>>> top.geometry('500x100')
''
```

Another option is to use a container widget, like a `Canvas` or `Frame`, of your desired size into the window you'd like to work with. Then you can place other objects into this container:

```
>>> top2 = tk.Toplevel()
>>> frame = tk.Frame(top2, width=100, height=100)
>>> frame.pack()
```

When you `pack()` the `frame`, `top2` is automatically adjusted to fit `frame`'s size.

Using `geometry()` to set a size of AxB results in the same size window as placing an AxB widget into a dynamically-sized window - that is, if you put in a widget (or use `geometry()` to set the window size to) the width of your screen, the window's borders will be just outside the visible area of your screen.